# Changing where a function's behavior is described is causing an error?

Tags: c++, function, debugging, object

I have the following class declaration (I've tried to remove as much excess code as possible):

```
class List {
    public:
        struct Node {
            int value;
        };
        Node * findNode(unsigned int) {
            return new Node;
        }
};
```

This gives no error. However, as soon as I define the function "findNode" outside of the class, I get an error; here's the code:

```
class List {
    public:
        struct Node {
            int value;
        };
        Node * findNode(unsigned int);
};

Node * List::findNode(unsigned int index) {
    return new Node;
}
```

Now, when running the code, I get an error saying "LinkedList.cpp:9:1: error: 'Node' does not name a type".

I would appreciate any help in determining the problem.

Comment: Also if that's a header file you need to use `inline` on definitions outside the class. Or you'll get a link error as soon as two source files include the same header.

Answer (score 4):

Until the compiler encounters `List::` it has no idea the `Node` you're talking about is a member of `List`. Change the definition to:

```
List::Node * List::findNode(unsigned int index) {
    return new Node;
}
```

The "naked" `Node` inside the function is fine because by that time the compiler knows the function is a member of List.

Comment: @PawełStawarz, no, read the last sentence of the answer: _"The "naked" `Node` inside the function is fine because by that time the compiler knows the function is a member of List."_  i.e. after `List::findNode` names are looked up in the scope of `List`.